# Linux file ACL and secondary groups

Tags: linux, ldap, access-control-list

**The Problem:**
CentOS does not seem to look at secondary groups when using ACL's on a folder or file

**Scenario:** CentOS 6 basic install, uses LDAP accounts to authenticate users. I am trying to setup fairly complex permissions on some folders. I have ensured that the file system is mounted with ACL support and determined that LDAP users are able to log in correctly.

**Steps to Reproduce:**
As a test I have a simple folder structure. The folder `test1` is owned by root and has 770 permissions, I have added another group to that folder `setfacl -m g:testgroup:rwx test1/` The getfacl output for the folder looks like this:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: share/test1/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:testgroup:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

The user `andrew` belongs to the domain group and testgroup as shown by `groups andrew`. The group domain is the users primary group. If the user andrew tries to read anything located in test1 a permission denied error was shown. If however the users primary group is changed to testgroup the user can then interact with the contents of the folder.

Can anybody tell me what is going on here and if there is a way to get the expected behaviour?

**EDIT** This appears to be a problem related to LDAP. I just tested using local user accounts and everything works as expected.

Comment: Have you done a "getent group" and verified no group is actually there TWICE and DIFFERENT? Also, check "id" for the users involved that group lists have not been truncated due to implementation limits (this used to be a metric b.... with NIS and might also be a problem with your LDAP implementation). Sorry for being able to offer only generic advice there...

Comment: @rackandboneman 'getent group' does not have any groups repeated. And 'id' of a user shows they belong to the relevant groups, nothing appears to be truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say this problem is related to the use of LDAP for user information. Your Centos6 machine is configured in a way that is incompatible with the LDAP server, so that when it tries to get the list of supplementary groups the user belongs to, it doesn't find anything.

Unfortunately there are several standards for how to interpret LDAP attributes relating to POSIX groups - rfc2307, rfc2307bis, IPA

Centos 6 uses SSSD for managing interwork with remote directories and authentication databases. The default settings for SSSD are to use rfc2307.

You will probably find your LDAP server is using rfc2307bis. We have a Centos 5 directory server, it was configured by default for rfc2307bis. As a further complication, our C5 directory was using the attribute 'uniqueMember' instead or 'member' for group members.

To fix it, edit /etc/sssd/sssd.conf and add the following lines:

```
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_group_member = uniqueMember
```

You might also like to refer to the following:

- man pages for sssd.conf and sssd-ldap
- http://www.couyon.net/1/post/2012/04/enabling-ldap-usergroup-support-and-authentication-in-centos-6.html
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=580402

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at the **numeric** ids of both the groups the user belongs to, and the ACL of the directory? Try `getfacl -n test1` and compare the groups listed with the output of `id -G andrew`. See if there is any discrepancy there and try resolve it.

Comment: The groups do match up, as do the numeric ID's so I don't think that is the root issue.

Comment: Could it be that the user belongs to too many groups? Is this reproducible with a user that is a member of only a couple of groups?